# Physics package causes partial differential to show smaller than other differential term

Tags: physics

I was trying to implement the Physics package, but the partial differential font is compiling to a smaller font compared to the other text.  Can the physics partial differential font be scaled up to the same size as the regular fonts?  Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{physics}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d\mathbf{P}_{T}}{dt} = {\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{dx}{dt} \\[2.5ex]
\dfrac{dy}{dt} \\[2.5ex]
 \dfrac{dz}{dt}
\end{pmatrix}} ={\begin{pmatrix}
  \pdv{x}{\theta_{1}} \dfrac{d\theta_{1}}{dt}  +   \dfrac{dx}{dr_{2}} \dfrac{dr_{2}}{dt} + \dfrac{dx}{dr_{3}} \dfrac{dr_{3}}{dt}\\[2.5ex]
 \dfrac{dy}{d\theta_{1}} \dfrac{d\theta_{1}}{dt} +   \dfrac{dy}{dr_{2}} \dfrac{dr_{2}}{dt}  +  \dfrac{dy}{dr_{3}} \dfrac{dr_{3}}{dt} \\[2.5ex]
 0 \hspace{1.3cm} 0 \hspace{1.3cm} 0
\end{pmatrix}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

After applying the first solution below, how to get all the terms to show up in the same size font?  Here is my modified code based on the first solution below:

```
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{J}_{P_{T}}(\theta_{1},r_{2},r_{3}) = {\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle
  \pdv{x}{\theta_{1}} &   \pdv{x}{r_{2}} & \pdv{x}{r_{3}} \\[2.5ex]
\displaystyle
 \pdv{y}{\theta_{1}} &   \pdv{y}{r_{2}} & \pdv{y}{r_{3}} \\[2.5ex]
 0  & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\displaystyle` for each row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{physics}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d\mathbf{P}_{T}}{dt} = \begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{dx}{dt} \\[2.5ex]
\dfrac{dy}{dt} \\[2.5ex]
 \dfrac{dz}{dt}
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle
  \pdv{x}{\theta_{1}} \frac{d\theta_{1}}{dt}  +   \frac{dx}{dr_{2}} \frac{dr_{2}}{dt} + \frac{dx}{dr_{3}} \frac{dr_{3}}{dt}\\[2.5ex]
\displaystyle
 \frac{dy}{d\theta_{1}} \frac{d\theta_{1}}{dt} +   \frac{dy}{dr_{2}} \frac{dr_{2}}{dt}  +  \frac{dy}{dr_{3}} \frac{dr_{3}}{dt} \\[2.5ex]
 0 \hspace{1.3cm} 0 \hspace{1.3cm} 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also define your own `dpdv` that is displaystyle pdv.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{physics}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\dpdv{}{\displaystyle\partialderivative}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{J}_{P_{T}}(\theta_{1},r_{2},r_{3}) = {\begin{pmatrix}
  \dpdv{x}{\theta_{1}} &   \dpdv{x}{r_{2}} & \dpdv{x}{r_{3}} \\[2.5ex]
 \dpdv{y}{\theta_{1}} &   \dpdv{y}{r_{2}} & \dpdv{y}{r_{3}} \\[2.5ex]
 0  & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!  How would you get this solution to work if all the terms were  `\pdv` and wanted the font to show up normally, i.e. like shown in your first  solution?

Comment: @Joe Can you add an example of such a term please?

Comment: Hello @Harish Kumar, please see my edited question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Answer updated.